# Openlayers: Vector Features instead of Markers

Tags: openlayers

I want to place a symbol o a Map. E.g.

[image: Map Example]

So far I have used OpenLayers with `OpenLayers.Layer.Markers`. The code looks like this:

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat({{ location.lon }}, {{ location.lat }}).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        ), 15);

   var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat({{ location.lon }}, {{ location.lat }})
             .transform(
               new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
               map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
             );
   var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
   map.addLayer(markers);
   markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));
```

This works as excepted and shows the map above. But I can't get it to work with Vectors replacing the last 3 lines with:

```
     vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");
     vectors.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat))]);
     map.addLayer(vectors);
```

Is there any special magic needed to use `OpenLayers.Feature.Vector`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`OpenLayers.Geometry.Point`](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point.Constructor) receives two coordinates in its constructor and not an `OpenLayers.LonLat`.

```js
vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");
point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat.lon, lonLat.lat);
vectors.addFeatures([new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point)]);
map.addLayer(vectors);
```