# Decluttering too many point markers

Tags: javascript, php, openlayers, mashup, geoext

I want to solve a clustering problem 
 Thanks to  Mårten Wikström, he explained it nicely. 
I want to  implement the tile/sub tile partitioning  scheme using quadtree
My data is large data collected by volunteers. what cheapest architecture and tools is best recommended to design and visualize this data so that the points will not be cluttered on the map?

Is there some one solved same problem and can share the code and architecture design or recommend me some?

Comment: There are various clustering strategies you can employ in OpenLayers, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641919/openlayers-nice-marker-clustering for some good examples.

Comment: In general, though, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You might want to look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try a distance based clustering:http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps.

Comment: OP appears to be asking about OpenLayers, though the idea is the same.